# Facebook API posting photos/status updates very slow

Tags: php, facebook

I have users stored in a data base. I call them with a these functions in a loop but it takes like 5 to 15 seconds for each post. Its not the database code but only the posting functions that make it slow.  This is not all the code but what seems to me to be the most important.

Now that I look at the code I am wondering if I need to call the function GetContentsUsingCurl() in a loop. Someone helped me write this code but its slow
so I am trying to tighten it up.

example code called these function in a loop:

```
/// loop code
{
PostPhoto($fbId, $access_token);
PostText($fbId, $access_token);
}
```

My Question: Can I make this faster somehow?

```
function PostPhoto($fbId, $access_token)
    {
        global $PIC_URL;
        global $PIC_CAPTION;

        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbId . '/photos';
        $attachment =  array(
                'access_token'  => $access_token,
                'url'           => $PIC_URL
        );

        $result = GetContentsUsingCurl($url, $attachment);
        $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
        if( isset($result['error']) ) 
        {
            echo "Error Message: ".$result['error']['message']."<br/>";
            echo "Error Type: ".$result['error']['type']."<br/>";
            echo "Error Code: ".$result['error']['code']."<br/>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<pre>";
            echo "Photo posted successfully!<br/>";
        }
    }

    function PostText($fbId, $access_token)
    {
        global $TWEET_URL;
        global $TEXT_MESSAGE;
        global $AD;

        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbId . '/feed';
        $tweet = GetContentsUsingCurl($TWEET_URL, "");
        $tweet = "\"".trim($tweet)."\"\n\n"; 
        $attachment =  array(
                'access_token'  => $access_token,
                'message'  => $tweet.$TEXT_MESSAGE.$AD
        );

        $result = GetContentsUsingCurl($url, $attachment);
        $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
        if( isset($result['error']) ) 
        {
            echo "Error Message: ".$result['error']['message']."<br/>";
            echo "Error Type: ".$result['error']['type']."<br/>";
            echo "Error Code: ".$result['error']['code']."<br/>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<pre>";
            echo "Feed posted successfully!<br/>";
        }
    }


    function GetContentsUsingCurl($url, $attachment)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Judging by the url pattern, I don't think there's much you'll be able to do.  I would try to optimize a task like this by setting up a batch of user IDs and tweets and making one big POST (i.e. sending 100 tweets at a time).  Facebook would have to support that, though.

Comment: I was noticing one thing. Is it possible these are doing the same thing every time and calling the website and trimming them over and over again for each post. Is it possible that we could make this a global var and call it once? Here are the lines: 

$tweet = GetContentsUsingCurl($TWEET_URL, "");
$tweet = "\"".trim($tweet)."\"\n\n";

Comment: Will you always post the same tweet to the entire list of users?  If so, definitely pull those lines out of the loop.  You could use a global variable or change `PostText` to `function PostText($fbId, $access_token, $tweet)`

Comment: Yes, same tweet. Ok, I thought so. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you're sending the same tweet for the whole list, you can definitely get some improvement from doing this:

```
$tweet = GetContentsUsingCurl($TWEET_URL, "");
$message = $tweet.$TEXT_MESSAGE.$AD;
/// loop code
{
  PostPhoto($fbId, $access_token);
  PostText($fbId, $access_token, $message);
}
```

And then change your PostText function to:

```
function PostText($fbId, $access_token, $message)
{
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbId . '/feed';
    $attachment =  array(
            'access_token'  => $access_token,
            'message'  => $message
    );

    $result = GetContentsUsingCurl($url, $attachment);
    $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
    if( isset($result['error']) ) 
    {
        echo "Error Message: ".$result['error']['message']."<br/>";
        echo "Error Type: ".$result['error']['type']."<br/>";
        echo "Error Code: ".$result['error']['code']."<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "Feed posted successfully!<br/>";
    }
}
```